# need to make a ball travel in the angle it was hit from

Tags: javascript, physics, collision, velocity, trigonometry

```
self.hitBall = function(ball, x, y) {
    var angle = Math.atan2((x - ball.centerX), (y - ball.centerY));
    ball.velocityY = (Math.sin(angle) * 10);
    ball.velocityX = (Math.cos(angle) * 10);
};
```

So the function takes in the ball, which has a centerX variable and a centerY variabe. The x and y passed into the function is the x and y is the point the ball was hit. I want to make the ball travel in the direction it was hit from.

Not really sure why my code isn't working.. it's behaving very strangely and I'm not that good with trigonometry so I'm not really quite sure why it isn't working.

Comment: I think this would fit better on the http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ game dev.

Comment: You said your code behaves strangely. Can you try this instead? `Math.atan2(ball.centerY - y, ball.centerX - x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

- `Math.atan2()` takes the arguments in (y, x) order. Most languages (Java, JavaScript, C, etc.) do this (except Microsoft Excel and some others, which use (x, y) order).
- When you say "[make] the ball travel in the angle it was hit from", you want to subtract the hit point from the ball point. In other words, the vector is (ball.centerX - hitX, ball.centerY - hitY).

Thus, the solutions:

- Solution 1:

  ```
  var angle = Math.atan2((ball.centerY - y), (ball.centerX - x));
  ```
- Solution 2 - do vector math without angles (equivalent calculation):

  ```
  var dx = ball.centerX - x;
  var dy = ball.centerY - y;
  var norm = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  ball.velocityX = (dx / norm) * 10;
  ball.velocityY = (dy / norm) * 10;
  ```

Comment: Hey thank you so much! Solution 1 worked but I had to do it like 

var angle = Math.atan2((y - ball.centerY), (x - ball.centerX));